# Distribution of the Sum of Dependent Bernoulli Random Variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, independence, bernoulli-distribution, indicator-function

Suppose that we have two random variables consisting of an indicator function like below:
\begin{align*}
V_1=1[c_1\geq u_1] \\
V_2=1[c_2\geq u_2]
\end{align*}
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants, and $u_1$ and $u_2$ follow the standard normal variables.

Thus, $\Pr[V_1=1]=\Phi(c_1)$ and $\Pr[V_2=1]=\Phi(c_2)$, and as we can see, $V_1$ and $V_2$ follow Bernoulli distributions with the probability $\Phi(c_1)$ and $\Phi(c_2)$, respectively.

**Q 1.**
Here, I would like to know the distribution of $V_1+V_2$ when $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not independent. (If they are independent, then the distribution may be binomial)

**Q 2.** Additionally, I am also wondering whether $V_1+V_2$ can be expressed using another indicator function like $V_1+V_2=1[c_2\geq u_3]$.

I guess, it is impossible because that it is possible implies that the sum of two Bernoulli follows a Bernoulli distribution.

If my conjecture is correct, then is it possible to express $V_1+V_2$ using only one random variable $u_3$? (This question is possibly equivalent to **Q 1**)

I have been striving to solve the questions above, but so far no progress has been made.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** In general, dependency between $V_1$ and $V_2$ can be dealt with by writing the joint probabilities of the outcomes of these variables:

$$\begin{matrix}
\theta_{00} \equiv \mathbb{P}(V_1=0, V_2=0) & & & \theta_{01} \equiv \mathbb{P}(V_1=0, V_2=1), \\[6pt] 
\theta_{10} \equiv \mathbb{P}(V_1=1, V_2=0) & & & \theta_{11} \equiv \mathbb{P}(V_1=1, V_2=1). \\[6pt]  
\end{matrix}$$

The distribution of the sum $V_1+V_2$ is then given by:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(V_1+V_2 = 0) &= \theta_{00}, \\[6pt]
\mathbb{P}(V_1+V_2 = 1) &= \theta_{01} + \theta_{10}, \\[6pt]
\mathbb{P}(V_1+V_2 = 2) &= \theta_{11}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In the case where $V_1$ and $V_2$ depend on underlying random variables, the probabilities $\theta_{00},\theta_{01},\theta_{10},\theta_{11}$ can be written as functions of the underlying joint distribution of those random variables, and you would then obtain the required form by substitution of the expressions for those probabilities.

---

**Q2:** No, this is not possible.  As you correctly point out, this form would give $\mathbb{P}(V_1+V_2 = 2)=0$, which does not capture the distribution correctly.